# TBATS (generalized holtwinters) produces error : Error in attributes(best.model$errors)

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, holtwinters, arima

I'm trying to apply tbats model on timeseries data. This dataframe contains values in the range of `0` to `1`. Before applying model , I replaced all the 0 values with `NA`'s (because I wanted to take log of the dataset and the log of 0 values will give -inf) and and then took the log of all the values to prepare dataframe for `TBATS`.

After all the changes as mentioned above, dataframe looks like below:

```
     y_ds0           timestamp
1    -2.9957323 2017-08-07 01:01:00
2    -3.2188758 2017-08-07 01:01:10
3    -3.2188758 2017-08-07 01:01:20
4    -3.5065579 2017-08-07 01:01:30
5    -3.5065579 2017-08-07 01:01:40
6    -3.9120230 2017-08-07 01:01:50
7    -3.9120230 2017-08-07 01:02:00
8    -4.6051702 2017-08-07 01:02:10
9    -4.6051702 2017-08-07 01:02:20
10   -4.6051702 2017-08-07 01:02:30
11   -4.6051702 2017-08-07 01:02:40
12   -4.6051702 2017-08-07 01:02:50
13           NA 2017-08-07 01:03:00
14           NA 2017-08-07 01:03:10
15           NA 2017-08-07 01:03:20
16           NA 2017-08-07 01:03:30
17           NA 2017-08-07 01:03:40
18           NA 2017-08-07 01:03:50
19           NA 2017-08-07 01:04:00
20           NA 2017-08-07 01:04:10
21           NA 2017-08-07 01:04:20
22           NA 2017-08-07 01:04:30
23           NA 2017-08-07 01:04:40
24           NA 2017-08-07 01:04:50
25           NA 2017-08-07 01:05:00
26   -2.5257286 2017-08-07 01:05:10
27   -2.6592600 2017-08-07 01:05:20
28   -2.8134107 2017-08-07 01:05:30
29   -2.9957323 2017-08-07 01:05:40
30   -3.2188758 2017-08-07 01:05:50
31   -3.5065579 2017-08-07 01:06:00
32   -3.5065579 2017-08-07 01:06:10
33   -3.9120230 2017-08-07 01:06:20
34   -3.9120230 2017-08-07 01:06:30
35   -3.9120230 2017-08-07 01:06:40
36   -4.6051702 2017-08-07 01:06:50
37   -4.6051702 2017-08-07 01:07:00
```

It has 1000 more rows in the data.

On the above dataframe, I applied `TBATS` model using below code:

```
tk_ts_dataframe <- tk_ts(ts_df ,
            start = 1,
            freq = 6,
            silent = TRUE)

fit <- tbats(tk_ts_dataframe)

forecast <- forecast(fit, h = 1)
```

I'm getting error like below:

> Error in attributes(best.model$errors) <- attributes(origy) :    dims
>   [product 1435] do not match the length of object [236]

Please help me in resolving this. `auto.arima()` works completely fine in this dataset.

Comment: Possibly the missing values which are handled by auto.arima but not by tbats.

Comment: @RobHyndman , thanks for the response. What should be the ideal way to deal with this. As of now, what I did is, instead of replacing 0 with NA's, i replaced it with 0.001 and the model worked.

Comment: Try using the imputeTS package. See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/imputeTS/vignettes/imputeTS-Time-Series-Missing-Value-Imputation-in-R.pdf for details.